# subprocess popen Python

Tags: python, bash, shell

i am executing a shell script which is starting a process with background option &. The shell script is called from python script which hangs.

Shell script:

```
test -f filename -d &
```

python file

```
cmd =["shellscript","restart"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
pid = proc.pid
out, err = proc.communicate()
returncode = proc.poll()
```

Python file hangs and it won't return out of the python process. Also python process is an automated one.

Comment: What is your "cmd"?

Comment: cmd is nothing but the list [<shell script> restart].

Comment: `test -f filename -d &` doesn't look like a valid command, at least if `test` is the standard posix test binary or shell builtin. Is this just a placeholder for something else?

Answer (score 1):

The call to `proc.communicate()` will block until the pipes used for `stderr` and `stdout` are closed. If your shell script spawns a child process which inherits those pipes, then it will exit only after that process also has closed its writing ends of the pipes or exited.

To solve this you can either

- redirect the output of the started subprocess to `/dev/null` or a logfile in your shell script, e.g.:
  `subprocess_to_start >/dev/null 2>&1 &`
- use `subprocess.DEVNULL` or an open file object for `stderr` and `stdout` in your python script and drop the `communicate()` call if you don't need the output of "shellscript" in python

Answer (score 0):

A comma is missing in your `cmd` list:

```
cmd =["shellscript", "restart"]
```

Comment: sorry thats my mistake. But the shell script starts a process with option as background which is started by python.